Spark worker cannot connect to Kafka Broker
I setup a  SparkCluster according to this instruction and I wanted to extend it's functionality by adding Kafka broker.
However I have problem with connecting Spark worker to Kafka broker
I get timeout error because of:
24/12/08 19:18:09 WARN NetworkClient: [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.

I tried other configurations such as

localhost:8081
localhost:8082
localhost:9092
localhost:9093
kafka:9093 -> different error, error below:

Couldn't resolve server kafka:9093 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka

Consumer.py code
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaReader") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

    schema = StructType().add("message", StringType())

    df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9093") \
    .option("subscribe", "crypto_topic") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()
    
    messages = df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.message")
    
    query = messages \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
    query.awaitTermination()

Parts of docker-compose.yaml file
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      #- KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
      #- KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      #- KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      #- ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      #- KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      #- KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9092      
      #- KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      #- KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    networks:
    - my_network

  spark-consumer:    
    container_name: spark-consumer
    command: python3 consumer.py
    build:
      context: ./docker/spark_consumer  
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_CLOUD_JSON_KEY_FILE=${GOOGLE_CLOUD_JSON_KEY_FILE}
    ports:
      - 8082:8081
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/workspace
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    networks:
    - my_network

This worked previously without trying using Spark Cluster
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'crypto_topic',
        bootstrap_servers='kafka:9093',
        auto_offset_reset='earliest',          
        enable_auto_commit=False,
        group_id = 'api_data'  
    )


Python has AdminClient as well. What are you hoping to see with Spark?
